# xsd string validation with regex

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xsd, this is part of it:

```
   <xs:complexType name="Shape">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Shape object
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="archimate:ViewNodeType" >                          
          <xs:attribute name="shapeId" use="required">
             <xs:simpleType>
                 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                   <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]" />
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>                    
            </xs:attribute>
```

I need to validate the shapeId from an xml. The shapeId is a string which can contain letters and numbers, for example this:

```
 shapeId="5dad54ae0c0ba639c4a5a800"
```

However the pattern that I use validates correctly the shapeId in [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/95029), this xsd throws the exception that 'The shapeId attribute is invalid - The value in invalid according its datatype String.'
What I am missing here?

Comment: The pattern you link to on regextester.com is completely different to the one in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern must match *entirely*. Your's only matches a single letter. You're missing a quantifier like `*` or `+` or `{24}`:

```
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" />
```